# Input from scanner to string array

Tags: java, arrays, input

/*This is my error message

The Game of Life.
How many steps in time? 1
What size is the grid? 5
Enter the intial grid layout:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at GameOfLife.main(GameOfLife.java:23)

### The input should look like this:

--o--
--o--

### ---o-

or something like that.  I want to make each line a string and into an array.  what is wrong with this code?*/

```
import java.util.*; 
public class GameOfLife { 
  public static void main(String[] args) { 
    int steps = 0; 
    int size = 0; 
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); 
    String [] layout = new String[size]; 
    System.out.println("The Game of Life."); 
    System.out.print("How many steps in time? "); 
    steps = sc.nextInt(); 
    System.out.print("What size is the grid? "); 
    size = sc.nextInt(); 
    System.out.println("Enter the intial grid layout:"); 
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) { 
      layout [i] = sc.nextLine(); 
    } 
  } 
}
```

Comment: import java.util.*;
public class GameOfLife
{
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
  int steps = 0;
  int size = 0;
  
  Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
  String [] layout = new String[size];
  
  System.out.println("The Game of Life.");
  System.out.print("How many steps in time? ");
  steps = sc.nextInt();
  
  System.out.print("What size is the grid? ");
  size = sc.nextInt();
  
  System.out.println("Enter the intial grid layout:");
  
  for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
  {
   layout [i] = sc.nextLine();
  }  
 }
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First read the `size` then create the array

```
// int steps = 0; 
// int size = 0; 
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); 
// String [] layout = new String[size]; 
System.out.println("The Game of Life."); 
System.out.print("How many steps in time? "); 
int steps = sc.nextInt(); 
System.out.print("What size is the grid? "); 
int size = sc.nextInt(); 
String [] layout = new String[size]; // <-- here.
```

As it is you are using the default value of `0` from your declaration of `size`. In future, I suggest you declare variables with as narrow a lexical scope as you can. That prevents this sort of bug.

Comment: thank you!!  I just change the nextLine to sc.next to make it work.  with nextLine was one entry short.